# Is it possible to change your spawn point?

Tags: starbound

Is it possible to change the location you beam to on a planet? I've been to a couple of planets that have no usable resources near the spawn point and everything is a good distance East or West. It would be nice to be able to always beam down to there instead.

Answer (score 25):

It is not yet possible to change your spawn point. The developers have stated in a [blog post](http://playstarbound.com/the-future-of-starbound/) that it will be included in a future release.

Comment: I don't have any primary sources, but there are a few mentions of it in [this thread](http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php?threads/beam-down-bacon.33794/)

Comment: fair enough, I guess "not at present" is a valid answer in itself :)

Comment: Yeah, I don't like leaving this kind of answer, but its the only correct one right now. As soon as the item is implemented, I'll come back and change this (and if I forget, post a comment on it and I'll see it), so whether you want to accept this or wait til then is up to you.

Comment: Has there been any update on this?

Comment: There's still no in-universe way to do it, but it looks like you can set your spawn point on a planet by using `/admin` and `/setspawnpoint`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the location you beam down to on a planet by using a [Human Flag](http://starbounder.org/Human_Flag):

> Human Flag is a decorative object available in the basic crafting menu to all Human characters immediately after beginning the game. Each race has a unique flag available.
>
> Flags act as teleporter bookmarks. Once placed, **interacting with a flag opens the bookmark window and the location can be saved**. Flags do not allow the player to teleport to other bookmarks or their ship, they can only be teleported to from either a ship or a full size teleportation pad.

Comment: Don't all races have their own flags?

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to change the original spawn point.

You can use Flags or teleporters to create custom spawn points.

In a future release they might introduce Space navigation overhaul:
http://playstarbound.com/spaceoff/

And seems that this **might** make possible to choose the landing zone

Answer (score -2):

yes, create platform around 100 blocks above where you spawned, simply obstructing the location.. and sb will give you new spawnpoint... I accidentally did that.. glad I hasn't make much but the new spawn point is not desired :/
Also /admin and /setspawnpoint

Answer (score -4):

yes you can change you spawn list by going to your player folder every player has a folder and if you found your player you will need to match the file name with a file name hipworld  at the end of the file name. to change the spawn you will need another file and change the hipworld to your hipworld file name and then your can change the whole world